# Identify Duplicates with different combinations on excel sheet

Tags: vba, excel

Please I am trying to extract details from two excel sheets to output to another sheet.

the first sheet contains names , these names are made up of three or two characters. The first sheet contains only one "name" field

The second sheet consists of two fields, a "name" field and a corresponding "amount" field

The second sheet can contain multiple combinations of the name field per row in the first sheet .  for example if row  1 on the first sheet has nam as "Ann Salma Jane" . There are at least two rows with different combinations row 1 may be "Ann Salma", Row 2 may be "Salma Jane"

The goal here is to do a lookup on sheet 2 for each row in Sheet 1 , the output should be on another sheet.

I have tried many options but I have not been able to get the right VBA code to do this for me.

```
Sub Macro1() 
' ' Macro1 Macro ' ' 
Range("G9").Select ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
"=VLOOKUP(names!R[1]C[-3]:R[5]C[-3],Transactions!R10C6:R28C7,1,1)"
Range("G9").Select Sheets("names").Select 
End Sub
```

Comment: What kind of lookup?

Comment: I want to extract for each row in sheet one , all the rows with the possible name combinations on the second sheet .

Comment: And please show us your code.

Comment: Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    Range("G9").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=VLOOKUP(names!R[1]C[-3]:R[5]C[-3],Transactions!R10C6:R28C7,1,1)"
    Range("G9").Select
    Sheets("names").Select
End Sub

Comment: Sorry ,I am not too good with using VBA to code straight up. I used a macro